# Load a spark sql table in database table

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

Is there any way to load spark sql table in database table as it is , as we were doing in sql

```
insert into database_table select * from sparksql_table.

pg_hook = PostgresHook(postgres_conn_id="ingestion_db", schema="ingestiondb")

connection = pg_hook.get_conn()

cursor = connection.cursor()

spark = SparkSession \
    .builder \
    .appName("Spark csv schema inference") \
    .config("spark.sql.warehouse.dir", warehouse_location) \
    .enableHiveSupport() \
    .getOrCreate()\
```

i am able to run this :

**spark.sql("select * from MetadataTable").show()**

but not this   :

**cursor.execute("select * from MetadataTable")**

Answer (score 0):

Open spark-shell with this package
spark-shell --packages org.postgresql:postgresql:42.1.1

```
val url = "jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/dbname"

 def getProperties: Properties ={
 val prop = new Properties
 prop.setProperty("user", "dbuser")
 prop.setProperty("password", "dbpassword")
 prop.setProperty("driver", "org.postgresql.Driver")
 prop
 }

val df = spark.sql("""select * from table  """)

df.write.mode("append").option("driver", "org.postgresql.Driver").jdbc(url, 
"tablename", getProperties)
```

After this, you can check the table in your postgres database. Also, refer to different mode options that spark offers and choose the suitable one for you.

Answer (score 0):

You can find this python equivalent to @Ghost9's answer:

Initialize your spark session with the postgres driver package like below **(Check the correct version)**:

```
spark = SparkSession \
    .builder \
    .appName("Python Spark SQL basic example") \
    .config("spark.jars.packages", "postgresql-42.2.5.jar") \
    .getOrCreate()
```

Then you can connect to the jdbc with the following function:

```
def connect_to_sql(
        spark, df, jdbc_hostname, jdbc_port, database, data_table, username, password
):
    jdbc_url = "jdbc:postgresql://{0}:{1}/{2}".format(jdbc_hostname, jdbc_port, database)

    connection_details = {
        "user": username,
        "password": password,
        "driver": "org.postgresql.Driver",
    }

    df.write.jdbc(url=jdbc_url, table=data_table, mode="append", properties=connection_details)
```

You can find different modes:

```
    append: Append contents of this :class:DataFrame to existing data.
    overwrite: Overwrite existing data.
    ignore: Silently ignore this operation if data already exists.
    error (default case): Throw an exception if data already exists.
```